# Prolog problem modeling: objects with different colors

Tags: prolog

I'm new to writing Prolog and would like to know how to state the following properties in a way that's useful for later reasoning.

- There are N objects.
- Every object has a color.
- There are three possible colors: red, green, blue

Let's assume there are two objects: object 1 is red, object 2 has a different, unspecified color. How can I ask Prolog for possible colors of object 2? I'd expect green and blue.

My code so far:

```
object(obj_1).
object(obj_2).

color_value(red).
color_value(green).
color_value(blue).

color(Obj, Val) :- object(Obj), color_value(Val).
color(obj_1, red).

different_color(O1, O2) :- color(O1, X), color(O2, Y), X \= Y.
different_color(obj_1, obj_2).
```

When I query for possible colors of `obj_2`, Prolog includes `red`. So I'm doing it wrong somehow.

```
color(obj_2, A).
A = red ;
A = green ;
A = blue.
```

I suspect there's something wrong with how I use color and different_color.

Comment: Stylewise, `color(Obj, Val) :- object(Obj), color_value(Val).` is a kind of typing. You really don't need it in this setting. Worse, it interferes with setting up the facts about "object - color" relationship. Because when you ask "does `obj_1` have color `green`", Prolog will find `color(Obj, Val) :- object(Obj), color_value(Val).` and say yes because `obj_1` is an object, and `green` is a color. Whereas you really want to say "the color of `obj_1` is `red` and no other color": `color(obj_1, red).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `color/1` offers redundant solutions for `color(_, red)` or `color(obj_1, _)`. Your clause for `color(Obj, Val)` needs to exclude the case where `Obj` is `obj_1` or `Val` is `red`.

A simplistic approach could be:

```
color(Obj, Val) :-
    dif(Obj, obj_1),
    dif(Val, red),
    object(Obj),
    color_value(Val).
color(obj_1, red).
```

Also, consider @DavidTonhofer's comment about style. :)